# How to make a function that returns another function (that returns another function and so on...)

Tags: swift

I'm trying to have a bunch of functions (with no input parameters), that optionally returns another function of the same kind, to achieve something like this:

```
var next = f1
do {
    next = next()
} while next != nil

...

func f1() -> ????? {
    return f2
}

func f2() -> ????? {
    return f3
}

func f3() -> ????? {
    return nil
}
```

so to have a function return the next function that will be used.

The problem is I can't seem to find a combination of function signature/return values that works...

The only ways i found so far require each function to have a different signature depending on the one that it returns, but that'd prevent from storing it in a variable, and have any logic to decide which function to return...

Comment: Optionally means it returns an Optional.

Comment: Yes, I mean an Optional function, so it's either a function or nil

Comment: Can you explain what you're really hoping to do? For example if you just want to make a specific function chain that you can travel down as far as you like, then simply curry the functions together.

Comment: I'm trying to have a loop where I go trough a series of function, where each one will do some operations and then decide what the next function will be, not necessarily always the same one, so I can't just simply code a chain of function and call them...

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: You can decide what function to return and return it, inside the function. What you cannot do is return a choice of functions with two different signatures.

Comment: That's exactly why I was thinking of them as all having the same signature. Maybe I'm not entirely clear on the currying but I don't see how that would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by making your own OptionalFunc enum:

```
enum OptionalFunc {        
   case Some(() -> OptionalFunc)
   case None

    var hasFunc: Bool {
        switch self {
            case .Some(_):
                return true
            case .None:
                return false
        }
    }

    func next() -> OptionalFunc {
        switch self {
            case .None:
                return .None
            case let .Some(block):
                return block()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then define your functions like so:

```
func f3() -> OptionalFunc {
    println("3")
    return .None
}

func f2() -> OptionalFunc {
    println("2")
    return .Some(f3)
}

func f1() -> OptionalFunc {
    println("1")
    return .Some(f2)
}
```

And run through them like this:

```
var next: OptionalFunc = .Some(f1)
while next.hasFunc {
    next = next.next()
}
```

All placed into a playground, this outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: From a couple of quick benchmarks it seems that not only it works, but it's also faster than the other solution I had (have next as an instance variable and instead of returning the value setting it directly in  each function)